# TestNG: possibility to run @BeforeSuite only related to the group of executed @Test

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng

I have one class with tests, each test included in different groups. For all groups should be done some preparation to run the tests successfully. I'm using several @BeforeSuite for different test-groups.

**Here is my example:**

```
public class TestClass {

  @BeforeSuite(groups = {"groupOne"})
  public void setUpGroupOne(@Optional("parameter") String parameter) {
    // some logic only for groupOne
  }

  @BeforeSuite(groups = {"groupTwo"})
  public void setUpGroupTwo() {
    // some logic only for groupTwo
  }

  @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
  public void onStart() {}

  @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
  public void prepareForTest() {}

  @Test(groups = {"groupOne"})
  public void testGroupOne() {
    // some test steps with setUp for groupOne
  }

  @Test(groups = {"groupTwo"})
  public void testGroupTwo() {
    // some test steps with setUp for groupTwo
  }

  @AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
  public void onFinish() {}

  @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
  public void cleanUpAfterTest() {}
}
```

If run group from xml-file - there are no problems at all, all methods runs only for related group.

But if I want to run only one test-method - for example, run just `testGroupOne()` from the my class - both @BeforeSuite methods are executed - for "groupOne" and for "groupTwo".
And the problem is the my test `testGroupOne` didn't get the necessary parameter which I'm applying in `setUpGroupOne`.

How I can to avoid running methods that not related to the group of my executed @Test when I'm run it from the class (not xml)?

Maybe there are any another solution for my task?